# Adding new row before rows which their td has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. Why am I not able to add a new row `.green`  before any `tr` which has a `td` with class of `.red`

As you can see following code adding the new tr inside the tr:

```js
$( '<tr class="green"><td>new row<td></tr>' ).insertBefore( " tr > td.red" );
```

```css
.red{
background:red;
}
.green{
background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `.parent()` with  `.before()`

```js
$( " tr > td.red" ).parent( ).before( '<tr class="green"><td>new row<td></tr>');
```

```css
.red{
background:red;
}
.green{
background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:has()` as you want to insert before `tr` which has `td.red`.

`.insertBefore( " tr:has(td.red)" );`

**Check this out:**

```js
$( '<tr class="green"><td>new row<td></tr>' ).insertBefore( " tr:has(td.red)" );
```

```css
.red{
background:red;
}
.green{
background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector was for `td`, not `tr`.

You need to use `:has` selector to check if `tr` contains `td` with class red

```
$( '<tr class="green"><td>new row<td></tr>' ).insertBefore( " tr:has(td.red)" );
```

**Demo**

```js
$( '<tr class="green"><td>new row<td></tr>' ).insertBefore( " tr:has(td.red)" );
```

```css
.red{
background:red;
}
.green{
background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```